# Find and sed: how to replace files in place?

Tags: sed, find

I want to replace a phrase composed of two words separated with a space with another two words:

```
find . -type f -exec sed 's/w1 w2/w3 w4/g' {} +
```

However, even if the pattern 'w1 w2' occurs in many files on the current dir, nothing seems to change.

Comment: You may find the option `-i` of sed useful. At the moment the replacement is only done on stdout without effect on the file.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? What happens when you run `sed 's/w1 w2/w3 w4/g' filename`?  Do you understand your error now?

Comment: @Jens good answer, but unfortunately people come to StackOverflow looking for answers, rather than looking for how to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the `-i` or `--in-place` option for sed.  Otherwise it won't actually change the file.  Check the [sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) for more info.

Side note: you'll find it easier to troubleshoot if you first get this working without `find`.  Start small, then build up.